# Displays value of those part of the selected parameter

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Sorry to bother you again, i have difficulties in formulating my query . i have two columns with a date values. (see sample below)

```
Posting Date                col B
Feb 02,2013              feb 01, 2013
Feb 02, 2013            
feb 15, 2013
mar 03,2013              mar 01, 2013
april 12, 2013           april 12, 2013
```

if my parameter is a range of date based on col B (ex. where colB between 02/01/2013 and 02/28/2013).
I want to show all value in Posting date which is part of the date range i had filtered. say, having month of Feb and 2013 as year

results:

```
Posting Date                col B
Feb 02,2013              feb 01, 2013
Feb 02, 2013            
feb 15, 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  Is your field type of your Posting_Date column a Date?  If so, then this should work:

```
SELECT Posting_Date, ColB
FROM YourTable
WHERE Posting_Date >= '2013-02-01'
   AND Posting_Date < '2013-03-01'
```

I prefer using `>=` and `<` rather than `BETWEEN`.

If your Posting_Date field is stored as a varchar, then use `STR_TO_DATE`:

```
SELECT Posting_Date, ColB
FROM YourTable
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(Posting_Date , '%M %d,%Y') >= '2013-02-01'
   AND STR_TO_DATE(Posting_Date , '%M %d,%Y') < '2013-03-01'
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5eaf6/3)

Comment: thank you for your prompt reply, but there are thousands of values in posting dates and col B .. that is just a sample. How will i do it?

Comment: @user1840952 -- not understanding your question.  Are you looking to search by column B's month and year instead?